# How to disable auto input focus in Vimium?

Tags: google-chrome, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, navigation

Some websites autofocus on input fields as you open a page. That makes some Vimium functions difficult to use because you have to quit the input field first.

Is it possible to disable autofocus at all from Vimium or another third-party Chrome extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an option called "Don't let pages steal the focus on load" in the advanced options that should do this.

source: https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/1904

Answer (score 2):

You can disable javascript autofocus in Chrome using extension TamperMonkey. (Firefox's GreaseMonkey for Chrome)

Once you've installed it in chrome, you can download this user script:

- [Fix Focus](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/185115)

It works fine with Vimium and lets you use mail.google.com with vimium extension.

Okay, it does not work 100% of the time, but it sure helps.

Other scripts (if it doesn't work for a specific website):

- Unfocuser extension from the same website
- [ComFreek's script](https://superuser.com/questions/694125/how-to-disable-autofocus-on-input-fields-in-chrome): add it to the extension manually

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it is not possible to disable 'autofocus' with Google Chrome.  I could see it being an annoyance, but it's going to have to remain that way for now.

Maybe you could be the one to build the extension :)

Answer (score 1):

I just press `Esc` and then the input looses the focus, immediately after that I can use Vimium shortcuts.