# Override "focus" events in my browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

Is there a tool that will allow me to prevent specific pages from refocusing my keyboard when I load them?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

**Background:** when Google searching, I often visit a lot of pages in the results for 3 or 4 seconds and then want to go back. Unfortunately, backspace doesn't navigate the page because a search box is focussed. Moving the trackpad up to the back button so many times is tedious on a smaller laptop.

**Page Navigation Solution:** Simply hitting the `Tab` key before `Backspace` leaves the box and causes backspace to navigate away from the page. `Alt+LeftArrow` also works on Windows systems.

.

**Actual Userscript Solution:** Pulled from here: [Superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/694138/436580)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable auto-focussing
// @author         ComFreek <comfreek at the following domain 'outlook' with the TLD 'com'>
// @description    Disable auto-focussing
// @include *
// @version        1.0
// ==/UserScript==

var maxTime = 3000;
var timeoutInterval = 5;

var usedTime = 0;
var isManualFocus = false;
function check() {
    if (!isManualFocus && document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
        console.log("BLURRED");
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
    usedTime += timeoutInterval;
    if (usedTime < maxTime) {
        window.setTimeout(check, timeoutInterval);
    }
}
check();


document.body.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
        console.log("MANUAL CLICK");
        isManualFocus = true;
    }
});

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
    isManualFocus = true;
});
```

All credit goes to [Comfreek](https://superuser.com/users/137286/comfreek)

I hope this helps!

Comment: {Alt}-{left arrow}?

Comment: I didn't know about that one! Thanks! Let me know how the userscript goes, if it doesn't work I can try to whip up some code for a Chrome extension..

Comment: Also consider {CTRL}+`L`.

Comment: Would it be possible to tailor this script to focus the address bar, in order to discern our article from the others?